# How to pull email addresses from outlook?

Tags: .net, com, outlook

I'm trying to write an outlook extension that will allow the use to hover over an in-company email address and see their seat location, similar to how you can see their lync availability. I'm being told, however, that this isn't possible to pull email addresses from outlook, nor have an extension activate when the user hovers over them. Is that true? And if not, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all the email information from Outlook just fine. What you cannot do however is figure out what is the object that the user is hovering the mouse cursor over is. You can try to use the Accessibility API to check what a control at the given position is, but it will not let directly retrieve anything but the string displayed on the screen. You can course try to match that value against the MailItem.Recipients collection, but I don't know how reliable that will be.